# How to add multiple stylesheets for mobile and tablet in opencart theme

Tags: css, media-queries, opencart, stylesheet

Im using an edited version of the default theme. I want to have multiple css files for mobile and tablet. I've added mobile.css and tablet.css to the header file right after the stylesheet.css code

However the stylesheet is not loading. NO changes are made if I resize the browser.

My header.tpl looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html dir="<?php echo $direction; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html dir="<?php echo $direction; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html dir="<?php echo $direction; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<base href="<?php echo $base; ?>" />
<?php if ($description) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($keywords) { ?>
<meta name="keywords" content= "<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<?php if ($icon) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $icon; ?>" rel="icon" />
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach ($links as $link) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $link['href']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $link['rel']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">

<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $style['href']; ?>" type="text/css" rel="<?php echo $style['rel']; ?>" media="<?php echo $style['media']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php foreach ($scripts as $script) { ?>
<script src="<?php echo $script; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $google_analytics; ?>
</head>
```

Thanks

Comment: I made it working. There was a server problem which I fixed. Thanks anyone for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to resize display with screen width you have to use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link re`l="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 640px)">
```

In this example main.css is used in all case, and mobile.css will be applied when screen will pass below 640px
(and you can add another one to lower resolution if needed)

In your code, mobile css should be applied all the time, so maybe you should use your brower console to check if links are good...

and check if you don't overwrite your css in

```
<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $style['href']; ?>" type="text/css" rel="<?php echo $style['rel']; ?>" media="<?php echo $style['media']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

**Create opencart theme**

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-introduction--cms-21786
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-part-two--cms-21865
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-part-three--cms-21890
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-part-four--cms-21932

**To clear opencart cache:**

- image cache located at in public_html/image/cache
- if you have vqmod public_html/vqmod/vqcache
- system cache public_html/system/cache

Do not delete the cache folder only the contents within them folders.

Comment: I can't get media queries to work in stylesheet.css too. With !important it works, but without it, it doesn't. Your example is the same as what I have, so makes no sense.

Comment: @kees . Do you want override any css without using !important.

Comment: because if your code is as you posted you may overwrite css in your php call (maybe put your mobile css after this) `<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>...<?php } ?>`

Comment: Will try that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The stylesheet is not loading I guess, don't know why.

Comment: can you teel wich css would not load ? only the mobile.css who works when you use !important ? did you tried to remove your browser cache ?

Comment: Mobile.css is not working at all, I made a mistake. It's not loading.

Comment: as i said, you should check in the browser console (webmaster tools) if all is ok ;)

Comment: I've did that already. The css file is not showing up in the <head></head>

Comment: remove browser cache, test with another browser, send us what console say ... :P

Comment: Ive already cleared cache. This is my head section (from chrome dev tools) http://puu.sh/l32xv/05b80afcc7.png as you can see. No mobile.css file

Comment: this is "Element" of the Developper tools, check Console of the Developper tools and Network. And check that you modified the good file on your server ! Check that you don't have file cache server side too

Comment: Why should I check console? That's empty obviousy.. I don't have file cacher server side

Comment: cause console tell you if there trouble like missing files (404)

Comment: Obviously. That's empty, because If mobile.css is not recognized, it's not missing because it doesn't exist for the browser.

Comment: you can check you encoding file (if it is UTF-8 without bom) but anyway, with what your posted there no reason to explain your error, if it is in the cold, it should appear in source code of the page (by the way did you checked source code ? it is not the same as inspect element)

Comment: Again, obviously. The page source is exactly the same as inspect element..  No mobile.css. Only stylesheet.css and ecslideshow.css

Comment: that mean you may call the bad file server side, cause source code is what your server send.

Comment: I've edited, catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl, should be the right one. or is there another header file

Comment: search for header.tpl in your project and try to add some random code like <script>console.log('this is a test');</script> code should appear in the page, and console should show "this is a test"

Comment: Looks like im editing the wrong header file, because I've added a alert script that triggers if jquery is loaded, nothing is happening, so.

Comment: by the way, you said " With !important it works, but without it, it doesn't" so ... ?

Comment: No that was because I edited the stylesheet.css file, I think opencart is using a cached version of header.tpl

Comment: so remove opencart cache and retry :P

Comment: If I edit my footer.tpl it's working, but header.tpl isn't.

Comment: Cache problem is fixed, but I still need to add !important to make it work.

Comment: if the original css get !important, you have to use !important to overwrite it

Comment: That doesn't mak sense, because of Media queries, there should be another way.

Comment: post source code of css else, how can't we know whats wront ? by the way you have 3k+ points so if you don't know a basic trouble like that, i wonder how you get thoose point...

Comment: I'm not an opencart pro, I'm a programmer, not an opencart guru.

Comment: css coding still the same, you still didn't posted the css sources

Comment: I'm just testing with background color: @media screen and (max-width:480px) and (min-width: 100px) {
 .container{
  background-color: white;
 }
}

Comment: It's just a different background color, nothing more.

Comment: inspect `.container` element with your browser developper tools and check the css property

Comment: i added more info about opencart theme.